# iPhone, how do I specify which territories my in app purchases are available?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'd like to provide different in app purchases in different countries / territories.

But I can't see an option for this.

Can I do this / have I missed something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You can only limit the app regions which will also reflect the IAP regions.

I advise raising a RDAR for now but many others create different apps in different regions to get around this.

Comment: The only way at present is to remove from sale completely in the US. if you then need a US app submit another for only that region without the IAP

Comment: can't you in your code check where you are and then show/hide the in app purchase button?